# Need to get access of "Process Builder" in Salesforce for non admin users

Tags: salesforce

Need a Process builder access for the Non-admin user in Salesforce Org.

**Here I have following permissions based on my profile/user,**

1. Flow User Enabled - User Record
2. Manage Flow Permission enabled - System permission(Profile).
3. And having a View All permission for all objects - Object Settings (Profile).

So I don't know where I am missing anything more for access process builder.

Where

> currently if I check process builder via quick find i am not able to
>   see the option (link for process builder).

Helps appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ZbRNAA0

Comment: @NagaSaiA Sorry, Still I don't find any System permission in profile as named 'Manage Force.com Flow'.Could you please help, Where I can find it.

Comment: @NagaSaiA so as per your given link need run flow system permission also required to access process builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system permission "View All Data" is separate from the object-level "View All" permission, and is not the same as having "View All" on each object.

As documented in [Create a Process](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_create.htm&type=5), the permissions required are

> To create, edit, or view processes: Manage Flow AND View All Data

You will need to add the View All Data system permission. Be aware that this bypasses large sections of the Salesforce security architecture.

Comment: thanks for an answer. I giving the  view all data system permission. But unfortunately still i get "URL No longer exists" error. :(

Comment: Would you please edit your question to give an example of a URL that is not working for you? It is not typical to link directly to a Process Builder definition; most users access them through the Setup menu.

Comment: yup.your correct david. But in here initially i just checked in access process builder by setup menu with help of quick find search. But i am unable to see the option then why i try to hit the url of the process builder. And thanks for advice i will update my question now.